# Is there a better word for the place that is "indoors" in the context of a large site or property?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that would contrast with "grounds" when referring to various parts of a site or property. Essentially, the "inside" part of a building or structure.

I don't really like "indoors" because it presupposes doors and feels more like a state of being than a place.

I was initially thinking of the word "proper," but according to my dictionary that doesn't make sense.

**edit:**

I think the comments have indicated I need to be a bit more specific. The word I am looking for is effectively the opposite of the word "grounds". Say, you're taking a tour of Washington D.C. Part of your tour might take you on the White House *grounds*. Another part of the tour might take you inside, and you would be touring the White House **_**.

In many cases, you can just say "White House" alone and this will make sense, but I am wondering if there is a word to specifically refer to the *place* that is NOT the "grounds".

Comment: Would these areas all have ***roofs**?* If doors aren't necessary, how about ***walls**?* Would an open-sided [gazebo](http://www.gazebos.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/garden-gazebo-02.jpg) count, for example?

Comment: The "*interiors*"? "*Interior areas*"? "*Intramural* spaces"?

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm, I think what I'm looking for wouldn't even presuppose a roof or walls -- rather, this refers to the _object_ of a _named architectural structure_. So, if the gazebo itself is _the structure_, then yes, but if the gazebo is incidental and the named structure is something different, then the gazebo is part of the "grounds".

Comment: @DanBron Ooh, "interior" is certainly better than "indoors", but isn't quite a perfect match.

Comment: Why not "inside" ?

Comment: I'm not sure there's a better word than _indoors_. _inside_ works when the building is the entirety of the site. But if there's a property that has a main building and a gazebo, I don't think _inside_ would be considered to include the gazebo. Maybe _indoors_ wouldn't, either. There may not be any word that includes both the building and auxiliary structures.

Comment: @NReilingh: Now I'm really confused. The areas you want included within this term don't necessarily have to have walls *or* roofs? Would an open-air swimming pool qualify? A patio? Decking?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps *shelter* or the phrase *sheltered space*.  *Collins* defines *[shelter](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/sheltered)* as

> something that covers or protects; protection, or place affording protection, as from the elements or danger

If you are focusing on the purpose rather than the structure, perhaps *dedicated space* may suit, especially if you pair it with the intended usage.

Governmental agencies often use the term *building area* to describe the land covered by the structure, as in this [local code](http://ecode360.com/5161787).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the comments - *interior* is in contrast with *exterior*. E.g. you get *interior* paint and varnish which will deteriorate quickly if you apply it to an outdoor or exterior surface. But *exterior* paint can handle sun and rain etc.

If you are referring to property in the sense of land surveying or property valuation, you would refer to *land* and *improvements*, which are anything built on the land (which presumably make it more valuable than the way it was originally)

Mmmm - I would have just commented, but I don't have 50 points reputation

Comment: Do *improvements* include swimming pools and tennis courts?

Comment: Yes they do. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_improvement

Comment: Damn. We were so close!

Answer (score -1):

You could use "On Site". .....